# `perl -pe` match only start of file?

Tags: string, perl, multiline

I'm trying

```bash
perl -pe 's;\A(?!syntax:);syntax: glob\n\n;' .hgignore
```

On a file with these contents:

```
dist
node_modules
.vscode
```

The output I expect is:

```
syntax: glob

dist
node_modules
.vscode
```

With the caveat that I can run it repeatedly and it won't keep pre-pending.

I use `\A(?!syntax:)` to anchor the regex to the start of the file and then `(?!` to say "not followed by". Looks like `\A` is matching the start of the line, not start of file.

How can I match only the very start of the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `-p` switch the file is read line by line, to start with.  So the code never sees the whole file, only one line at a time.

To "slurp" the whole file into `$_` do `perl -0777 -pe'...' file`. That `-0777` unsets the [input record separator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$/), so the "line" read by `-p` is really the whole file.  See [it in perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-0%5Boctal/hexadecimal%5D)

Then the regex will run on the multiline string with the whole file.

With a multiline string one often needs the `/m` [modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Modifiers), so that `^` and `$` match beginning and end of lines inside the string, while we have `\A` to match the beginning of the whole string. One also often needs the `/s` modifier, so that `.` matches a newline as well.

However, it seems that for your purpose those aren't needed. Then, without the `/m` modifier the `^` anchor matches the beginning of the string, just like `\A`.  But I do find `\A` still better as it expresses the intent clearly.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are having is stemming from the fact that -p implies -n, which evaluates the program for each line of the file.

Your problem can be solved by only attempting the substitution on the first line of the file.

```bash
perl -pe's{^(?!syntax:)}{syntax: glob\n\n} if $. == 1' .hgignore
```

Alternatively, you could tell Perl the whole file is one line with `-0777` or the newer `-g`.

```bash
perl -0777pe's{^(?!syntax:)}{syntax: glob\n\n}' .hgignore
```